# Можно ли разыменовывать end итератор из take_while?

Tags: c++, range

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    auto oneDigitNums = std::views::iota(1) |
                        std::views::take_while([](int i) { return i < 10; });
    auto [end, result] = std::ranges::fold_left_first_with_iter(oneDigitNums, std::plus{});
    std::cout << "Folding finished at " << *end 
              << " with the value " << *result
              << '\n';
}
```

Можно ли так разыменовывать `*end` или этот итератор уже считается невалидным?

Comment: Разыменовывать `end` неправильно, даже если бы он был валидным, ведь он указывает за пределами диапазона запрошенных объектов.